# Vertical concatenation of a variable number of Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have data that I need to gather in a very specific way. Right now, the data comes in the form of N arrays (of arrays) all of M length. M will be the same for all arrays for a given invocation.

So the following example has N=2 and M=3. The length of the final nested arrays is variable and can be 0 or more (but it will be an empty array of length zero)

```
[
  [
    ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']
  ],
  [
    ['e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h']
  ]
]
```

What I need is

```
[['a', 'b', 'e'], ['c', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'h']]
```

I can get a working answer but it's gross, and I was hoping someone had a more elegant approach.

Here's the (sort of) working solution:

```
const gatheredData = [[]];
const final = _.forEach(startData, (array, arrayIndex) => {
  // This is intended to handle the basecase creation of empty arrays
  if (_.size(gatheredData) < arrayIndex) {
    gatheredData.concat([]);
  }
  gatheredData[arrayIndex].concat(array);
});
```

That also seems to error out in edge cases I haven't quite drilled down into yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lodash you can use [`_.unzipWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unzipWith), and pass `_.concat()` as the iteratee:

```js
const arr = [[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']],[['e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h']]];

const result = _.unzipWith(arr, _.concat);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Very clean, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith)

```js
const startData = [
  [ ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'] ],
  [ ['e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h'] ]
];

const gatheredData = _.mergeWith(
  [[]], 
  ...startData, 
  (source1 = [], source2 = []) => source1.concat(source2)
  );

console.log( gatheredData );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option without lodash would be to first map the nested array within your array, where for each inner (leaf) array (eg: `['a', 'b']`), you concatenate with an array containing all inner elements at the same index (that you can obtain with mapping all other arrays), eg:

```js
const arr = [
  [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']],
  [['e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h']]
];

const zipArrs = ([first = [], ...rest]) => first.map(
  (arr, i) => arr.concat(...rest.map(other => other[i]))
);

console.log(zipArrs(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `flatMap` like this:

```js
const data = [
  [
    ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']
  ],
  [
    ['e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h']
  ]
];

const gatheredData = data[0].map((_, i) => data.flatMap(arr => arr[i]));

console.log(gatheredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
// Assuming your initial arr is called arrs
const result = [];

arrs.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach((subArr, index) => {
        if (!result[index]) {
            result[index] = [];
        }
        
        result[index].push(...subArr);
    });
});
```